# jsqmessageviewcontroller text alignment

Tags: text-alignment, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have problem on the text alignment when no outgoing avatar. it will reserve some gap on the text like the following:

[Gap Sample Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMHKk.png)

I tried to setup the sender message bubble width with the following code but it will mask the input text (eg input 123 but show 1 in the bubble)

```
CGFloat finalWidth = MAX(stringSize.width + horizontalInsetsTotal, self.minimumBubbleWidth) + self.additionalInset;

if ([messageSender isEqualToString:[layout.collectionView.dataSource senderId]]) {
        finalWidth = finalWidth - 25;
}
```

[Text Missing Sample Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZypI.png)

How can I cancel the gap?